# Montar timeline dinamicamente em html na pagina .aspx

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de pedir uma ajudinha ao fórum, para montar uma timeline dinamicamente em html utilizando o font-end asp.net ou code behind C#, em uma aplicação Web Forms com base de dados SQL. Preciso montar imagino, para isso um for each no código aspx para ir criando estruturas htmls com CSS no formato posts conforme atualizações... Vejam a estrutura em html:

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <!-- timeline time label -->
  <li class="time-label">
    <span class="bg-red">
                    10 Feb. 2014
                  </span>
  </li>
  <!-- /.timeline-label -->
  <!-- timeline item -->
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>

    <div class="timeline-item">
      <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:05</span>

      <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#">Support Team</a> sent you an email</h3>

      <div class="timeline-body">
        Etsy doostang zoodles disqus groupon greplin oooj voxy zoodles, weebly ning heekya handango imeem plugg dopplr jibjab, movity jajah plickers sifteo edmodo ifttt zimbra. Babblely odeo kaboodle quora plaxo ideeli hulu weebly balihoo...
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Read more</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- END timeline item -->
<!-- timeline item -->
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz, para fazer dinamicamente essa estrutura dentro de uma pagina .aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar repeater para isto:

```
<ul class="timeline">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptTime">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="time-label">
                <span class="bg-red"><%# Eval("DATA") %></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>

                <div class="timeline-item">
                    <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><%# Eval("HORA") %></span>

                    <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#"><%# Eval("LINK") %></a> sent you an email</h3>

                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <%# Eval("TEXTO") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Read more</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

e no seu code behind você recebe a base de dados;

```
RptTime.DataSource = datatable;
RptTime.DataBind();
```

Basicamente isto, veja mais sobre repeater aqui https://imasters.com.br/framework/dotnet/trabalhando-com-repeater-no-asp-net/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Perfeito Thiago Araújo, obrigado!
Bom trabalho.

Comment: Bom trabalho pra você também.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho experiência com .aspx, mas páginas dinâmicas geralmente utilizamos sua ideia, monte uma estrutura como o código informado onde a tag 'ul' estaria fora da repetição e as 'li' estariam dentro do seu for